# Thinktecture Identity Server v3 login page customization with loader

Tags: angularjs, identityserver3, identityserver4

I have overwritten the default view for login as I added my own file here:

[image]

What I do there is just to get the base file from the repo assets and tweak it a little bit in order to look more appropriate to my project. I have changed some colors, removed some stuff and added some javascript to it.

What I want to do now is to add a loader (spinner) that shows up when I click the "Login" button and goes away if eventually, I get some kind of error (wrong credentials or something). What is obvious there is that it is using angular and binds a model:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="model.errorMessage">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Error:</strong>
            {{model.errorMessage}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" ng-show="model.loginUrl">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form name="form" method="post" action="{{model.loginUrl}}">
...
```

Since I am not very experienced with it, I decided to ask you for an advice.

First of all, is it possible to overwrite the model itself so I can get a full control on it? Similar to **_login.html**

I was wondering if it is a good idea to have my loader (spinner) in a **div** that has **ng-show** dependent on **model.errorMessage** so every time there's an error we hide the loader or something like this. I could also use directly **errorMessage** property I believe.

Just want to see your opinion since all of the solutions that come up in my mind for this don't seem to be very elegant.

Comment: Do you want to use Angular? There is no requirement for that, you are free to throw it out completely if you wish.

Comment: @danijels Angular is fine. It would be more intuitive as long as I have access to the model itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you implement IViewService, you will be able to get to the model itself in IViewService.Login and can output whatever you want to the login page.

Documentation is here: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customViewService.html